# Can I add an elbow to my kitchen gas line to improve clearance with the range?

Tags: plumbing, gas

The gas stub out behind my gas range currently protrudes from the wall by about an inch too much for the range to sit tight to the wall.

I'm thinking of using a 90 degree elbow like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FY8HPG8) after the valve so that the pipe faces towards the direction of the flex pipe.

Is that considered safe and are there any codes prohibiting it? I'm hoping to avoid redoing the pipe if possible.

[image]

Comment: Is there enough room to give the valve a 1/4 turn to clockwise and the elbow at the wall a 1/4 turn  counter clockwise ? (*or visa versa if not enough room*) This would put the yellow line parallel to the wall.

Comment: I would just turn the valve 90 deg. clockwise, orienting it downward. Run the flex line back underneath it. Done deal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add fittings like a 90° elbow, with these caveats:

- Be sure it's legal for homeowners to do gas work in your jurisdiction.
- Be sure the part is rated for gas.
- Be sure you know how to properly seal threaded gas connections with thread compound or (gas rated) thread tape and good technique.
- Be sure you test with soapy water when you're done.

Comment: I have lived in areas that gas plumbing modification requires licensed plumbers. Some connections were allowed I believe after the shutoff valve. That was not clear to me I took it as the shutoff at the meter (probably not what they meant) the house passed inspection after the kitchen remodel.+

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you suggested, but it would be easier to do the below:

You already have an elbow aligning the pipe with the wall.  Just flip the elbow at the wall to the right.  Replace the existing cut-off valve with an in-line valve.  Clean all the threads before re-assembling. Use pipe thread compound or gas pipe tape on all the threads.  After you tighten all fitting. check for leaks.

If the height of the pipe is high enough, you could just give the elbow valve a 1/4 turn down.  The flex pipe would attach from the bottom and the flex pipe would be parallel to the wall.

Comment: Why is this easier?  This produces a more elegant result but requires replacing the valve, and if OP damages the valve or threads in the process will be left without gas to the entire house until it can be repaired.    OP's suggestion seems a lot easier, is downstream of the pictured shutoff, and costs $10.  The question is whether it is alllowed.